# Formik checkbox not showing tick when added in a map function

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a form built using Formik, in which I am adding 'Field' controls of type checkbox in the 'map' function of an array like so:

```
students.map(student => 
                <Field type="checkbox" name="checked" value={student.id} key={student.id}/>
            )
```

Although the values from the checkbox group are being populated correctly when I submit the form, the checkbox does not show the tick mark when selected. However, if the checkbox controls are placed outside the 'map' method, checkbox shows the tick mark as expected. Can someone tell me what is happening here? Since the number of checkboxes in my form is dynamic, I need the map method to place them in the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
{students.map(student => 
    <Field 
        type="checkbox"
        name="checked"
        value={student.id}
        key={student.id}
        checked={values.student.includes(`${student.id}`)}
    />
)}
```